# How to find the partial fraction when the denominator contain repeated root?

Tags: partial-fractions

I do not know how to find the partial fraction of the following form since the denominator contains a multiplicity of the root with an integer degree $n \geq1$

$$\frac{1}{{\left( {1 + x} \right){{\left( {x + \alpha } \right)}^n}}} = \frac{A}{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}} + \frac{B}{{{{\left( {x + \alpha } \right)}^n}}} +\cdots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thai-Hoc Vu I believe the answer would be

$\frac{1}{{{{\left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {x + 1} \right)}} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)}^{n - k + 1}}{{\left( {\alpha  + x} \right)}^k}}}}$

You can verify it on wolfram alpha
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fraction%20%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x%2Ba%29%5E6%29&fbclid=IwAR0oSj45UPZO_sCmJBv8EWeRkjXPWld2rgfIwF95L64mHF20nyTuYx4QLtg)

Answer (score 2):

The form to use is $${A\over1+x}+{B_1\over x+a}+{B_2\over(x+a)^2}+\cdots+{B_n\over(x+a)^n}$$ [assuming $a\ne1$]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, for example for use in integrals, could be handy the decomposition for $n>1$
$$
\frac{P_{n-1}(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\frac{A}{x-x_0}+\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{Q_{n-2}(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}\right]
$$
where $A$ and the coefficients of the $n-2$ degree polynomial $Q_{n-2}(x)$ have to be determined by polynomial identity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general method, when you have a *proper* rational function (i.e. the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator) with a pole of order $n$, consists in performing the division of the numerator by the other factor  *by increasing powers*, up to order $n$.

Here is how it goes here: first it simplifies the computations if the pole of order $n$ is $0$. So we begin by the substitution $t=x+\alpha\iff x=t-\alpha$, which yields the fraction
$$\frac1{(t-\alpha+1)\,t^n}.$$
To illustrate the procedure, I'll suppose $n=3$. This is the result of division by increasing powers of $t$ up to order $3$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\color{red}{\frac1{1-\alpha}-\frac t{(1-\alpha)^2}+\frac{t^2}{(1-\alpha)^3}}\\
\hline
1-\alpha+t &\Bigl(\begin{alignedat}[t]{5}
1 \\ -1&&{}-\frac{t}{1-\alpha}\\
\hline &&-\frac{t}{1-\alpha}\\&&\frac{t}{1-\alpha}&&{}+\frac{t^2}{(1-\alpha)^2} \\\hline
&&&&{}\frac{t^2}{(1-\alpha)^2}  \\
&&&&{}-\frac{t^2}{(1-\alpha)^2} &&{}-\frac{t^3}{(1-\alpha)^3} \\\hline
&&&&&&\color{red}{{}- \frac{t^3}{(1-\alpha)^3} }
\end{alignedat}
\end{array}$$

There for  from the equality
$$1=(1-\alpha+t)\biggl(\frac1{1-\alpha}-\frac t{(1-\alpha)^2}+\frac{t^2}{(1-\alpha)^3}\biggr)-\frac{t^3}{(1-\alpha)^3},$$
we deduce that
$$\frac 1{(1-\alpha+t)\,t^3}=\frac1{(1-\alpha)t^3}-\frac 1{(1-\alpha)^2\,t^2}+\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)^3\,t}-\frac{t^3}{(1-\alpha)^3(1-\alpha+t)}$$
Can you proceed?